# How to remove duplicates from a comboBox

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, combobox, duplicates

I'm reading strings from a text file to populate the options in a dialog box. The issue is that I need to remove duplicate values in the list. I'm working on Visual C++. I'm using Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: You should start posting some code showing what you've tried so far and what kind of problems you're finding.

Comment: I used the index values in the combobox to filter it out.
The FindString method returns the first index of the object found, so what I did was
index=ComboBox.FindString("");
and for the next iteration 
if(index<0)
    ComboBox.AddString("New Value");

This worked.

Comment: Isn't it an easier approach to not insert them beforehand in the combo if they allready exist? `FindStringExact` is your friend.

Comment: And BTW, you should not use `FindString` to check string equality because it only matches by the first characters. On https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/4e73b5df-0d2e-4658-9706-38133fb10513.aspx#ccombobox__findstring there is a very important word: **prefix**

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3szh5e7c(v=vs.110).aspx

public:
int FindStringExact(
 String^ s,
 int startIndex
)

Insert everything and then check using this?

Answer (score 0):

When you read the items from the text file use a [map](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s44w4h2s.aspx). it will eliminate all the duplicate entries and add the map entries into the list

Answer (score 0):

```
BOOL CRemoveDuplicatedTextInComboBoxDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    ...
    m_wholeText.AddString(_T("2"));
    m_wholeText.AddString(_T("3"));
    ...
    m_wholeText.AddString(_T("6"));
}

void CRemoveDuplicatedTextInComboBoxDlg::OnBnClickedRemove()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    INT nCount = m_wholeText.GetCount();
    if (nCount <= 0) return;
    CString csz_compare1;
    CString csz_compare2;

    for (int i = 0; i < nCount; i++)
    {
        m_wholeText.GetLBText(i, csz_compare1);
        for (int j = 0; j < nCount; j++)
        {
            m_wholeText.GetLBText(j, csz_compare2);
            if (csz_compare1 == csz_compare2)
            {
                m_wholeText.DeleteString(j);
                nCount--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.
What I did was use FindString to check for each new entry.
FindString returns the index of the first object found.
So whenver this index was lesser than 0, I add the string to the combo box